# Internationalization of FCM notifications in Flutter

Tags: flutter, localization, firebase-cloud-messaging

I follow this tutorial https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive.

I added `string.xml` to `android\app\src\main\res\values`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="accountBlocked">Account blocked</string>
</resources>
```

I am able to get a RemoteMessage in Flutter app in foreground with right `notification.titleLocKey`. But there is no `accountBlocked` key in `AppLocalizations.of(context)!`.

How can I get title from this? Should I manually download `string.xml` and process it within my app?

I see that the message works as expected in background (shows the title as expected).

Answer (score 0):

I added the translations to `.arb` files and then accessed the corresponding keys with `AppLocalizations.of(context)!`. I think it is the most effective way.